# Python Flask set_cookie domain attribute doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, setcookie

According to the [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/), I should be able to set a cookie with a domain path for domains besides my own like this:

```
resp = make_request(render_template(index.html))
resp.set_cookie('cookiekey', 'cookievalue', domain='notmydomain.example.com')
```

I was able to set cookies for my domain with just

```
resp.set_cookie('cookiekey', 'cookievalue')
```

and they were accepted by the browser (Chrome). However, when I try to set the domain, they don't appear in the browser. Further, testing with postman reveals that the Set-Cookie headers are sent, and are correct.

Does this mean the browser is simply ignoring my request, and if so how can I get it to accept my Set-Cookie headers?

Comment: The browser is simply rejecting the cookie due to a basic policy not being respected: the cookie must be set for the current domain or a subdomain of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you can't set cookies for domains completely separate from your current domain.

Setting cookies for domains outside of your control would pose an immense security risk. The `domain` attribute only allows you to set cookies for either the whole domain or a subdomain. This is how, for example, a system can log you in via a subdomain such as "auth.example.org" then redirect you to "example.org".

In practice, "unified" sign-in systems are complicated: challenges are used and data might be exchanged through a backend, not relying on the browser to properly allow other subdomains to access the original cookie.

Comment: So I discovered this while doing extensive postman testing, and thus have accepted this answer. As a follow up, if I owned a domain (example.com) and kept my website on a subdaomain (www.example.com) and pointed another subdomain to the server that needs the cookie (data.example.com), and then set the cookie to be used by the whole domain (\*.example.com), would a browser accept *this*?